# how to call a smart contract function from a light node

Tags: contract-invocation, light-clients

Since you can call a smart contract function locally inside a full node without spending gas,Can you do the same from a light node like by querying all related smart contract data or something like that.

Most people suggest using a third party node like infura,but I am wondering if it's possible to not rely on any third party and use a light node instead.
I saw a similar question asked [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/46577/does-an-ethereum-client-need-to-download-the-entire-state-of-a-contract-in-order) and the accepted answer was that the same process that a light node would use to check for getting an account balance would be used for querying smart contract data (then I guess with the full contract data someone can just run the same code that full node uses to execute it).

If this is possible,are there any available implementations of it (I couldn't find any myself)